# Would love some assistance/fix for this python code (regarding pandas data-frame) please

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am running into this warning in my Jupyter notebook and I am relatively new to python and coding in general. Any help would be appreciated :)

Warning/Error:

```
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

Code causing the error:

```
dataCollection = pd.DataFrame()
for file in list_of_files:
    procData = pd.read_table(file, header=None, sep='\s+')
    procData.columns = columns
    procData['subject_id'] = int(file[-5])
    dataCollection = dataCollection.append(procData, ignore_index=True)

dataCollection.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
dataCollection.head()
```

The output I am expecting would be a dataframe table with column headings.

Comment: What exactly is unclear in the warning (it's not an error)?

Comment: The warning tells you exactly what to do

Comment: The warning tells me to use pandas.concat but it's unclear on how I can use that in the above code

Comment: Even if `append` was not getting deprecated, using it repeatedly has a quadratic complexity. `concat` should be used **on all DataFrames at once**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you to use `pandas.concat` in place of `frame.append`.

```
dataCollection = pd.DataFrame()
for file in list_of_files:
    procData = pd.read_table(file, header=None, sep='\s+')
    procData.columns = columns
    procData['subject_id'] = int(file[-5])
    dataCollection = pd.concat([dataCollection, procData], ignore_index=True)
```

Of course, this is an inefficient way of concatenating an arbitrary set of frames. Get all the frames in a list, then call `concat` *once*.

```
frames = []
for f in list_of_files:
    procData = pd.read_table(f, header=None, sep='\s+')
    procData.columns = columns
    procData['subject_id'] = int(file[-5])
    frames.append(procData)

dataCollection = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=rue)
```